# Can I use both Junit 3 and Junit 4 in the same Android project?

Tags: gradle, android-studio, robolectric, android-testing, bamboo

I have an Android Studio project with existing AndroidTestCase unit tests, based on Junit 3.  I would like to explore introducing robolectric tests as well, not to replace, but to supplement, the AndroidTestCase tests.  Can I use both Junit 3-based AndroidTestCase tests and Junit 4-based robolectric tests in the same project?  Can I run both of them on my bamboo CI system?  How do I configure the project to support that?

Comment: I would expect it is possible - you can filter classes or put them in different folders, you could remove robolectric test classes when you build and run android tests, you could filter out android tests when you run robolectric tests. But at the same time I would expect that setup for this project will be hard to implement, understand and support. I would move android or robolectic tests in different module but I don't have much experience with having android and robolectric tests in same project

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to put Robolectric tests in a separate module under the same project.

To create a new module, go File -> New Module... -> Java Library. When that module is created, navigate to its `build.gradle` file and replace its content with the following lines:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/m2repository" } // Fix 'com.android.support:*' package not found issue
    mavenCentral()
}

evaluationDependsOn(":app")

apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    def androidModule = project(':app')
    testCompile project(path: ':app', configuration: 'debugCompile')

    def debugVariant = androidModule.android.applicationVariants.find({it.name == 'debug'})
    testCompile debugVariant.javaCompile.classpath
    testCompile debugVariant.javaCompile.outputs.files
    testCompile files(androidModule.plugins.findPlugin("com.android.application").getBootClasspath())

    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'

    testCompile('junit:junit:4.11') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    }
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.6.1'
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    scanForTestClasses = false
    include "**/*Should.class"
    include "**/*Test.class"
    include "**/*Tests.class"
}
```

This charges the module with Robolectric testing goodness and should serve as a good starting point.

Note that `:app` should be replaced with the name of your application's module.

For Robolectric tests, you would also need a Robolectric runner which might look like this:

```
public class ApplicationTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

    //Maximun SDK Robolectric will compile (issues with SDK > 18)
    private static final int MAX_SDK_SUPPORTED_BY_ROBOLECTRIC = 18;

    private static final String ANDROID_MANIFEST_PATH = "../app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml";
    private static final String ANDROID_MANIFEST_RES_PATH = "../app/src/main/res";

    /**
     * Call this constructor to specify the location of resources and AndroidManifest.xml.
     *
     * @throws org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError
     */
    public ApplicationTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
    }

    @Override protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {
        return new AndroidManifest(Fs.fileFromPath(ANDROID_MANIFEST_PATH),
                Fs.fileFromPath(ANDROID_MANIFEST_RES_PATH)) {
            @Override
            public int getTargetSdkVersion() {
                return MAX_SDK_SUPPORTED_BY_ROBOLECTRIC;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then just annotate test classes with this runner, for example:

```
@RunWith(ApplicationTestRunner.class)
public class PriorityExecutorSchedulerTest {
    ....
}
```

Tests from Robolectric module can be run with `gradlew test`.

Concerning Bamboo, AFAIK there is a possibility to run a custom script, so I would just put `gradlew test` in it and see how it goes.